# Openvpn to stream media to Android

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, android, openvpn

If I set up an openvpn rig like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35647/how-do-i-setup-openvpn-so-i-can-securely-use-the-internet-from-an-unsecured-hots), could I use the [official openvpn app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn) (or anything, I don't care as long as it's free) to stream videos from the home PC to my Android device when I'm away from home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your OpenVPN server is accessible from outside your home network, you should be able to access services on your home PC. You can use a HTTP server such as Apache or nginx to serve your content.

Comment: I now have OpenVPN running and I am able to connect to the VPN from my android device using the OpenVPN Connect app.  What additional steps must I take to access media on the PC running the OpenVPN server?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 Install a server (nginx for example), change its configuration to listen on at least the OpenVPN tun/tap interface (or all addresses). After that, you can access your media via the webservice listening on the OpenVPN server's private IP address. Do not forget to configure permissions appropriately, i.e., the nginx user must be able to read files and descend directories.